# How to optimize group_concat sub query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i optimize this query? It's taking a lot of time to execute.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`details_value`), details_key  
  FROM `correspondence_package_details` 
 WHERE `correspondence_id` IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`correspondence_id`) 
                                 FROM `correspondence_package_header` 
                                WHERE create_date BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30' 
                               GROUP BY `manual_package_id`,account_id) 
   AND (`details_key` = 'to' OR `details_key` = 'cc') 
 GROUP BY details_key;
```

Comment: IMO your subquery should not use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP BY`. What do you intend to do with your query? And format it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query optimization is both an art and science. By simply looking at the sql, you are limiting your options.

1. Run an explain plan on your query. Check for low performing join types and scans.
2. Add appropriate indexes on all join columns.
3. For date fields, sort the index based on whether you would normally be querying most recent or oldest records.
4. Regular run the optimize command on your databases so that the indexes and tablespaces get a quick tune up.

The query plan will be your best tool for this.